# how to use keep alive connection with angular2 http service

Tags: angular, rest, http, webservice-client, angular2-http

I made an angular application that is making http GET request every two seconds to update a dashboard. But too often I receive a HTTP error 429 (Too Many Request).

I saw in the Firefox developer tools that the request is "Keep Alive" with a time of 5 seconds, so I think each call is opening a connection to the server and not reusing it

How can I tell angular to reuse the connection? or how can avoid a 429? Only have 3 or 4 concurrent clients.

The relevant code is below:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.interval = Observable.interval(environment.dashboard_refresh_rate).subscribe(x => {
        this.getLockersFromService();
    });
    this.getLockersFromService();
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.interval.unsubscribe();
}

getLockersFromService() {
    this.http.get('/dashboard').subscribe(
        data => {
            this.showDashboard(data);
        },
        (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            this.showErrorResponse(err);
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a case for websockets https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API

Comment: yeah @jbrown but my backend is in Laravel (php). Im think is complicated to implement websockets in PHP. I don't think I could have a long lived php process.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/broadcasting

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple expire implementation I used.

What is does it has a session and send the session to the backend (every 30 sec). If a succes message pop up it will add 15mins to the **logoutTimer**. If the date is higher then logoutTimer then it will logout automatic.

**localStorage** is used for, if you open it again on the main page your session can be reactivated with timeFithTeen.

```
 constructor(private router: Router, private soap: SoapRequest) {  //soap is your rest 
        if (localStorage.getItem('logoutTimer') === null) {
            this.timeFithTeen();
        }   
    }



 ngOnInit() {
        Observable.timer(2000, 30000).subscribe(t => {
            let date = new Date();
            this.soap.keepAlive().then((response: any) => {
                localStorage.removeItem('logoutTimer');
                this.timeFithTeen();
            }), ((error: any) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
            if (date >= new Date(localStorage.getItem('logoutTimer'))) {
                localStorage.removeItem('sessionExpired');
                localStorage.setItem('sessionExpired', 'Session expired');
                this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
            }
        });
    }
        private timeFithTeen() {
        let logoutTimer = new Date();
        logoutTimer.setMinutes(logoutTimer.getMinutes() + 15);
        localStorage.setItem('logoutTimer', logoutTimer.toString());
    }
```